# WebGIS within Esri Storymap?

Tags: arcgis-online, web-gis, story-map

I want to create a simple WebGIS for kayak tours, including a background image map, routes and points of interest (POIs) with a lot of information in form of pictures and photos. Main interest is to display all the information, no analysis are required. Due to this, I think that the concept of Esri Storymaps would fit quite well.

Is it possible to integrate the WebGIS within an Esri Storymap and how?

If it is possible, I am not sure, if the WebGIS would have to be created first using ArcGIS Online, published and then be coupled to the storymap. Or if it can directly be implemented within the Storymap framework.

Answer (score 2):

How to make a Story Map is well documented at Esri's [How to Make a Story Map](https://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/how-to/) page.

> You can create your web maps in ArcGIS Online first and then reference
>   them when you build your story, but some of the apps also let you
>   create and edit your maps from within their interactive builders, so
>   you can do your mapping as part of building your story.

---

> Each app has a tutorial page that guides you through the authoring process.

Comment: So it depends on the Storymap App if it can be created within? 
Is it also possible to develop the WebGIS using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript and then integrate this to the story map? 
Is there also an API for the story maps to program/edit on one's own or does the builder has to be used?

Comment: That's two different questions from what you have asked here, and so should be asked separately.  Since you only want to "display all the information, no analysis are required" I think the term web mapping rather than web GIS would be more appropriate.